# how to get the date from listview in code behind?

Tags: listview, get, code-behind

i have one listview and i want use from data  in there .but

The program gives an error when receiving data

that do not recognize the word item

```js
            TextBox countText = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtcount");
```

```css
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtcount" type="text" runat="server" Width="30"></asp:TextBox>
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the error that's being thrown.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 40: 
Line 41: 
Line 42:             TextBox countText = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtcount");
Line 43:           
Line 44: